# ASP.NET MVC, CheckBoxFor() attribute problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I use CheckBoxFor() HtmlHelper like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.IsDeleted, new { myCustomAttribute = "myCustomAttribute" })
```

my checkbox have attribute, but hidden element not have.

```
<input myCustomAttribute="myCustomAttribute" id="IsDeleted" name="IsDeleted" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="IsDeleted" type="hidden" value="false">
```

How add atribute to hidden element? I do not want to write custom HTML.

Comment: can you explaine why you need this attribute in hidden field too?

Comment: The `CheckBoxFor()` method will not add attributes to the hidden input - its sole purpose is to post back `false` if the checkbox is unchecked. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @teo van kot I can't:) The explanation is too difficult.

Comment: @hitmanalt0160 it sounds like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @hitmanalt0160 role is for screen readers (in general for accessibility), hidden fields (and not visible items) are ignored by screen readers. If you need it for your JavaScript stuff then IMO you'd better to use class.

Comment: @Adriano Repetti  ok, I update code

Comment: If you edit-out ARIA attributes then question is: "what do you need attributes for?". It's kind of unusual to put more stuff on hidden fields, maybe there is something else to have same result...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way to achieve such functionality is to create custom helper :) Below simple helper from http://20fingers2brains.blogspot.com/2013/05/custom-checkbox-html-helper-in-mvc3.html :

```
public static class CustomCheckBoxHelper
{
    //This helper accepts name attribute. This method in turns calls our second overload.
    public static MvcHtmlString Custom_Checkbox(this HtmlHelper helper, string name)
    {
        return Custom_Checkbox(helper, name, false);
    }

    //This helper accepts name and isChecked boolean attribute. 
    public static MvcHtmlString Custom_Checkbox(this HtmlHelper helper, string name,bool isChecked)
    {
        return Custom_Checkbox(helper, name, isChecked, null);
    }

    //This overload accepts name, isChecked and htmlAttributes as parameter.
    public static MvcHtmlString Custom_Checkbox(this HtmlHelper helper, string name,bool isChecked,object htmlAttributes)
    {
        //Creating input control using TagBuilder class.
        TagBuilder checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");

        //Setting its type attribute to checkbox to render checkbox control.
        checkbox.Attributes.Add("type", "checkbox");

        //Setting the name and id attribute.
        checkbox.Attributes.Add("name", name);
        checkbox.Attributes.Add("id", name);

        //Adding the checked attibute based on parameter received.
        if (isChecked)
            checkbox.Attributes.Add("checked", "checked");

        //Merging the other attributes passed in the attribute.
        checkbox.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(checkbox.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is the hidden input? And where are the `value` attributes? And strong typed binding to the model property?